# 2D "array" or object python for filtering duplicates

Tags: python, dictionary, scripting, data-management

I'm trying to filter user duplicates from a database. There's a unique user_id and the full name. I'm comparing the names using `difflib.get_close_matches`

Now as the names aren't unique, I created a dictionary with the user_id as key and the name as related object. But comparing names like this requires to iterate over the full dictionary every time and accessing the names is kind of a pain.

I was thinking about just using a 2d-array (list) as it's quicker to get the data, but I don't really want to work with indexes (Imho it's a pretty ugly way to deal with the problem). 
Any suggestions on how to solve this issue in an elegant way are highly appreciated.
I'm still learning python btw.

Edit:
The dataset looks like this:

```
user_id  name

4050 John Doe
4059 John doe
4052 John Doe1 
9083 Napoleon Bonnaparte
7842 Mad Max
4085 Johnn Doe
4084 Alice Spring
5673 Fredy Krüger
4092 Alice Spring1
4042 Alice k Spring
4122 Max miller
```

In the end I need to find the user_ids for the names which are similary, that's why I am using `difflib.get_close_matches` So the list should look like the following in the end:

```
user_id  name


4050 John Doe
4059 John doe
4052 John Doe1 
4085 Johnn Doe
4084 Alice Spring
4092 Alice Spring1
4042 Alice k Spring
```

Comment: Sounds like you could just load it into a [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe and drop duplicates based on `user_id`?

Comment: Or have I misunderstood? You have duplicate names under different user_id? It would be better if you could give an example, it's not clear exactly what is duplicated or the criteria for determining a duplicate since names are notoriously difficult to deal with

Comment: It's my first post, sorry! Extended it as you suggested, thanks! Now it also should be clear that you indeed missunderstood. ;-)
My main issue is not comparing the names as difflib does the job quite well I think but just accessing the data in a simple, elegant and readable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you really want to go from name to id and not the other way around. The way to tackle the issue of full names not necessarily being unique is to have a list of user_ids against each full name. So, reverse your dictionary that has the user_id as key and the name as related object. Like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
lookup = defaultdict(list)
for id, name in mydict.items():
    lookup[name].append(id)
```

Now build a dict of close matches using `difflib.get_close_matches()`: key is full name, value is a list of potentially duplicate full names. It appears from your question that you already know how to do that.

Loop through your dict of close matches and report full name and id:

```
for name, duplicate_list in close_matches.items():
    for id in lookup[name]:
        print (id, name)
        for duplicate in duplicate_list:
            for id in lookup[duplicate]:
                if duplicate != name:
                    print(id, duplicate, "possible duplicate of", name)
```

I've put a `print()` call here for simplicity but you will almost certainly want to assemble the results into a list for further processing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it basically is what I wanted to avoid, lot's of nested loops and many different lists to check and compare and so on. But it seems like there's no elegant way to solve those "issues"...

Comment: Your data is many-to-one-to-many: one name can have several ids and several fuzzy matches. And you want to connect the attributes on both *many* sides together. That implies 3 loops and two sets of lists. That may be more than you want, but I can't see how it could logically be reduced.

Comment: Ok, yes, agreed; If I want to use get_close_matches it is what you said.

Comment: Shouldn't name and id be swapped in this line? `lookup[name].append(id) `

Comment: @cafntown No, that was the whole point of reversing your original dictionary. You want to go from full name to fuzzy match (which is also a full name, but a different one) and from there to id. So your lookup table needs to go from full name to id. And because you can (at least in principle) have duplicate full names, id can't be a single value, it needs to be a list, so that you can associate all of the ids with that full name. You chose id to be they key because it is unique, but you want to go from fuzzy match to id, so the full name needs to be the key, even if it is not unique.

Comment: Ok, that's quite brilliant, took me a while to catch it! Thanks a lot :D